# How am I saving image wrong ? (Flask & Kivy)

Tags: python, flask, kivy

I'm saving image into app's filesystem:

```
image_file1 = request.files.get('image_file1')
image_file1.save(GALLERY+f'/{new_user.id}/{image_file1.filename}', image_file1.filename)
```

Setting aside the fact that I need to use `secure_filename()` method before saving it into filesystem. This indeed saves the image in the right directory but it can't be opened.
The os recognizes that it is `jpeg` or `png` but when I check properties of
the image I see "0 bytes":

[image]

I didn't know I can save an image in a wrong way. What is happening here ?

**Update:**

```
data = {
            'first_name': self.ids['first_name'].text,
            'middle_name': self.ids['middle_name'].text,
            'last_name': self.ids['last_name'].text,
            'new_comment': self.ids['comment'].text
        }
files = {'image_file1': open(self.file_path1, 'rb'), 'data': json.dumps(data)}
headers = {'enctype': 'multipart/form-data'}
response = requests.post('http://localhost/users/add', files=files, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
image_file1 = request.files['image_file1']
filename = secure_filename(image_file1.filename)
image_file1.save(GALLERY+f'/{new_user.id}/{image_file1.filename}', filename))
```

Comment: That only adds extension one more time. The `filename` attribute already holds extension.

Comment: Using image object instead of image name had no effect.

Comment: On the web I can see the right way is to be passing a filename.

Comment: I added a solution, copied from a website of mine. Please check and tell me if it worked. I hope it will help

Comment: I'm starting to think there's something wrong how the image is being processed between front-end and Flask. I keep getting blank jpeg file.

Comment: Please add your html code as well (in your question). Is there a form named 'image_file1'?

Comment: Edit added. It's not html. I'm using Kivy on the front-end.

Comment: Maybe it's a Kivy issue. You would better add it in question tags, someone more experienced with Kivy could probably help

Answer (score 0):

Solution came from member of the Kivy community.

I ommitted `os.path.join()` in `image_file1.save(os.path.join(GALLERY+f'/{new_user.id}/{image_file1.filename}', filename))`

Thus `save()` method was getting 2 args instead of 1.